# Ionic2 Google and Facebook Auth Issue After Published to PlayStore

Tags: android, facebook, ionic2

My Signed APK was working fine with Google and Facebook Auth but not working in Play store Downloaded APP.

App Link Below

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uslpost.india&hl=en

Signed APK in Google Drive : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9NlCqqZhGkaVi1zVUgtbUtxbjA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Google:

Google released a new signing service in playstore publish console in which google will signin your app with his keystore. After signing... 
Open app -->Release Management---> App signing---> App signing certificate 
it will give you a new SHA which you have to add in your google developer console.

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNbVE.png)

For Facebook:
 When you click on facebook login button , it will give you a SHA code which you have to add in your Facebook app developer console.

Comment: Thanks santhosh jeremiah You saved my day